# How to guarantee a request completes, even if navigation occurs

Tags: javascript, tracking

I vaguely recall reading about an experimentally available javascript API for making requests which can continue to occur even if navigation happens. Does anybody know the name of this API?

I'm having trouble googling for what this would be called.

The common problem this solves is trying to track outbound clicks, where today we typically need to do something like:

```
$('a').click(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  url = ev.currentTarget.href;
  doSomeTracking(function() {
    window.open(url);
  });
});
```

But a preferred semantics would be:

```
$('a').click(function(ev) {
  doSomeTrackingEvenThoughWereGonnaBeNavigating();
});
```

Comment: Could you not track first, return a promise and after promise is resolved, navigate to the next page, like `DoTracking().then(navigate)`

Comment: If you find this magical unicorn, please let everyone know. The solution you have is good. I usually have the server respond immediatly to doSomeTracking, then do the work. So user clicks > sent to the server > server says okay > page navigation happens > server finishes the work.